# OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7Error: decrypt error

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, pkcs#7, smime

```
smime = OpenSSL::PKCS7.read_smime(File.read('encrypted_smime.p7m'))
p_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('pr_key.pem'))
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('cert.pem'))
smime.decrypt(p_key, cert)
```

In the `decrypt` line above, I am getting the error *`OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7Error: decrypt error`*.

I am not sure why this error is causing, as I am able to decrypt the `smime` using `openssl` command line tool properly. Also I have verified that the `cert` I am using is signed using the same private key that I am using in `p_key`.

Following is the command which is getting me the expected output -

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in encrypted_smime.p7m -inkey pr_key.pem -out decrypt_smime.pem
```

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: In case it matters, you can find the source code for the `smime` subcommand at [`<openssl src>/apps/smime.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/smime.c).

Comment: Actually the command line is working fine. I am looking for a `ruby` solution.

Comment: The source code for the `smime` subcommand is written in C. It will tell you the data structures and general steps you should be using in Ruby.